# php says everyday have diffrent seconds for time zone

Tags: php, timezone

i saw one of php bug report
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80308 
they saying 
"Apparently you're in one of the timezones where 2020-11-01 was more than 86400 seconds long."

after that i tested days second for diffrent time zone

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo date_default_timezone_get().'<br />';
echo strtotime('2020-10-03') - strtotime('2020-10-01').'<br />';
echo strtotime('2020-11-03') - strtotime('2020-11-01').'<br />';
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
echo date_default_timezone_get().'<br />';
echo strtotime('2020-10-03') - strtotime('2020-10-01').'<br />';
echo strtotime('2020-11-03') - strtotime('2020-11-01').'<br />';
```

and results.

```
America/New_York
172800
176400
Australia/Melbourne
172800
172800
```

why anyone have idea ? i didn't understand :)

Comment: We changed from daylight time to standard time on November 1. There was an extra hour that morning.

Comment: New York DST end on Nov 1st so the clock go backward 1 hour. The outout look correct

Comment: If you change your second test (Melbourne) to Oct 4th, you would also note a change in the other direction since AEDT started that morning (minus one hour)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: thanks , you guys will make me sleep well tonight :)